# Is there a name for website navigation that uses anchors on a single page rather than linking to different pages?

Tags: navigation

I keep running across sites where the navigation paradigm is linking to anchors on a single page rather than linking to different pages. Some examples: https://banksimple.com/ http://www.cornell.edu/nyc/

Is there a name for that technique?

Answer (score 2):

**Single page website**. Also **one page website**.

[50 Examples of Modern Single Page Website Designs](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CD4QFjAB&url=http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/inspiration/single-page-website-designs/&ei=O1KxTp6aHqnh0QH5_IG5AQ&usg=AFQjCNGfvBMx0XDX12OWZKGZjrugFG5F4A&sig2=kjhCQxPTJEBGHlYoKHvBfg)

[9 Beautiful One-Page Websites for Design Inspiration](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CEYQFjAC&url=http://mashable.com/2011/06/07/one-page-sites-design/&ei=O1KxTp6aHqnh0QH5_IG5AQ&usg=AFQjCNFCuofLV4_LBbfZ5fw7zPejD6lv9Q&sig2=8LjP12dBHutjdK4wAuv2Tw)

[20 Inspiring Examples of Single Page Websites | Inspiration](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0CFQQFjAE&url=http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/20-inspiring-examples-of-single-page-websites&ei=O1KxTp6aHqnh0QH5_IG5AQ&usg=AFQjCNGLl4l1HGI2bWMayhLU2wI-EH_ryQ&sig2=SabrGWi7ZvGagiIQPFhVsw)

These are all some links to some examples of them, but everyone seems to refer to them as one of these two terms.